# I need to check a list of directories if it contains a directory newer than 1 month before now

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'll try to explain what i have done until now.

First of all i have build the list of directories i want to investigate with the code below:

```
$MDIR="/home/user/scripts/fcron"
DIRS=`ls -l $MDIR | egrep '^d' | awk '{print $9}' | grep ^$ts-`
```

The DIRS list now contain directory ***names*** of the form :

```
NETGEAR-2013-06-30
NETGEAR-2013-07-01
........
NETGEAR-2013-05-05
```

Now i need to check all those directories (**contained in list DIRS**) and i need to find one that is newer than 1 month before now (e.g 27 or 29 days). In case i find one match i need to exit the script.

In 'pseudocode' i would write:

```
for dir is DIRS:
    if dir is newer than 30 days old:
       exit the script
    else:
       continue
```

My difficulty is in translating just the above 'pseudocode' in a bash script.

/////Latest Update/////

OK i have updated the part with the pseudocode with this:

```
    for DIR is $DIRS;
    do
    if (( $(stat -c %Y "$dir") < $(date +%s) - 3600*24*30 )); then
        echo "exiting!!"       
    exit
    else
        continue
    fi
    done
```

But now i am getting this :

```
 line 40: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting "do")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
dirs='dir1 dir2 dir3'

for dir is $dirs; do
    if (( $(stat -c %Y "$dir") < $(date +%s) - 3600*24*30 )); then
       exit
    else
       continue
    fi
done
```

Comment: I'll try later. I'am off to bed.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
  -newermt "$(date --date="1 month ago 00:00" --rfc-3339=seconds)"
```

Using your `DIRS`:

```
find $DIRS -maxdepth 0 -type d \
  -newermt "$(date --date="1 month ago 00:00" --rfc-3339=seconds)"
```